# What is major difference between Ext.Direct Pack and Ext.Air Pack

Tags: extjs

On official Sencha downloads page - http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/ those versions are between v 3.3 and v 4.0.

I couldn't find an proper FAQ on Ext.Direct Pack and Ext.Air Pack - for what they can be specialy used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext.Direct Pack - set of server-side realizations (on different languages) of ala-web services complying with ExtDirect protocol.

Ext.Air Pack - set of classes for running your application in Adobe AIR.